# SARIMAX with lagged exogenous variable

Tags: time-series, arima, econometrics

From what I understand, SARIMAX models exogenous variables are not lagged, i.e. to estimate $y_t$ value, you need $x_t$ exogenous variables, not $x_{t-i}$.

I could do a workaround by creating lagged variables to *trick* the model. Is this a correct approach or are there other better models for these kind of situations?

BTW: I'm trying to see if I can improve fruits prices (high seasonality) predictions by adding local weather and foreign exchange data.

Comment: Nothing says that your $X_t$ series cannot be lagged. So, yeah, the trick would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's gedankenexperiment for you: what if you created a new variable $z_t\equiv x_{t-1}$, and used it in your regressions instead of $x_t$? Surely SARIMAX would work with $z_t$ variable. There's your answer

Comment: Sure, that is what i meant with: "I could do a workaround by creating lagged variables to *trick* the model". But I wanted to know if for these situations other TS models are more suitable.